# Invalid Identifier with Joins

Tags: sql, oracle

I don't tend to ask questions regarding errors however this one is happening to me on every report I am doing. There is something fundamentally wrong with my approach and I need a solution and hopefully an explanation if possible. I need to convert multiple reports and on everyone I am getting this error in one way or another.

Here is my code.

I am getting Invalid Identifier on:

```
INNER JOIN Unit_instance_occurrences uio
ON uio.offering_organisation = ou.organisation_code
```

What I don't understand is that ***ou*** identifier *has* been defined.

Here is the full code:

```
SELECT pu.CALOCC_CODE,
  ou.FES_FULL_NAME,
  pu.UIO_ID,
  uio.FES_UINS_INSTANCE_CODE ||' '||uio.LONG_DESCRIPTION Crse_Desc,
  EBS_TUTORGROUPSLIST_SEL(pu.id,pu.UIO_ID) Grp,
  pu.PERSON_CODE,
  p.FORENAME,
  p.SURNAME,
  Upper(p.surname) ||', '||p.forename||' ('||pu.person_code||')' Student,
  pu.PROGRESS_CODE,
  pu.PROGRESS_STATUS,
  pu.PROGRESS_DATE,
  Marks.Absent,
  Marks.Late,
  Marks.Not_Expected,
  Marks.Present,
  Marks.Notified_Absence,
  Marks.Blanks,
  SUM( Marks.Absent+ Marks.Late+ Marks.Not_Expected+ Marks.Present+ Marks.Notified_Absence+ Marks.Blanks ) Poss_Marks
FROM people p,
  organisation_units ou,
  (SELECT red.session_code,
    red.OBJECT_ID UIO_ID,
    reds.person_code,
    SUM(reds.absent) Absent,
    SUM(reds.late) Late,
    SUM(reds.not_expected) Not_Expected,
    SUM(reds.present) Present,
    SUM(reds.notified_Absence) Notified_Absence,
    SUM(reds.blanks) Blanks
  FROM
    (SELECT reds.OBJECT_ID Person_Code,
      reds.REGISTER_EVENT_ID,
      reds.SESSION_CODE,
     -- COUNT(DECODE(reds.USAGE_CODE, 'O', 1)) Absent,
      --COUNT(DECODE(reds.USAGE_CODE, 'L', 1)) Late,
      --COUNT(DECODE(reds.USAGE_CODE, 'V', 1)) Not_Expected,
     -- COUNT(DECODE(reds.USAGE_CODE, '/', 1)) Present,
    --  COUNT(DECODE(reds.USAGE_CODE, 'X', 1)) Notified_Absence,
    --  COUNT(DECODE(reds.USAGE_CODE, NULL, 1)) Blanks
    FROM register_event_details_slots reds
    WHERE reds.session_code    = :P_Occurrence --Added Params from master
    AND reds.object_type       = 'L'
    AND reds.planned_end_date <= Sysdate) reds
  INNER JOIN register_event_details red
  ON red.register_event_id = reds.register_event_id
  AND red.session_code     = reds.session_code
  WHERE
    --red.REGISTER_EVENT_ID = reds.REGISTER_EVENT_ID
    --and red.SESSION_CODE = reds.SESSION_CODE
    red.OBJECT_TYPE = 'U'
  ) Marks
INNER JOIN Unit_instance_occurrences uio
            ON uio.offering_organisation = ou.organisation_code
INNER JOIN people_units pu
            ON pu.CALOCC_CODE  = Marks.session_code --(+)
            AND pu.PERSON_CODE = Marks.person_code  --(+)
            AND pu.UIO_ID      = Marks.UIO_ID       --(+)
            AND pu.uio_id      = uio.uio_id
            AND pu.person_code = p.person_code
WHERE
  --pu.CALOCC_CODE = Marks.session_code --(+)
  --and pu.PERSON_CODE = Marks.person_code --(+)
  --and pu.UIO_ID = Marks.UIO_ID --(+)
  --pu.UIO_ID = uio.UIO_ID
  --and uio.OFFERING_ORGANISATION = ou.ORGANISATION_CODE
  --and pu.person_code = p.PERSON_CODE
  pu.UNIT_TYPE                = 'R'
AND pu.CALOCC_CODE            = :P_Occurrence -- Added Params from master
AND uio.owning_organisation   = :P_Faculty
AND uio.OFFERING_ORGANISATION = :P_Division
AND uio.UIO_ID               IS NOT NULL
AND uio.FES_ACTIVE            = 'Y'
```

Comment: You're combining the ANSI and Oracle join syntax. Don't.

Comment: Can you tell me where the Oracle Join syntax is? I thought I got it all.

Comment: (Sorry I can't edit the previous one)
I looked at the linked example of the duplicate. Is it within the FROM clauses:  t1,t2,t3 and it should be achieved by t1 CROSS JOIN t2 etc?

Comment: You have commas between the tables in your FROM clause... between `people` and `organisation_units`. There is no obvious joining condition between the two, so in this case a CROSS JOIN would be appropriate. However, this is almost certainly incorrect... if you wanted to join the two together somehow then you've got to add the conditions in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I re-organise your joins, I get the following, which does ***not*** mix implicit *(using `,`)* and explicit joins *(using `INNER JOIN`, etc)*.

```
SELECT
  blah
FROM
  organisation_units ou
INNER JOIN
  Unit_instance_occurrences uio
    ON  uio.offering_organisation = ou.organisation_code
INNER JOIN
  people_units pu
    ON  pu.uio_id       = uio.uio_id
INNER JOIN
  people p
    ON  p.person_code  = pu.person_code
INNER JOIN
(
  yourSubQuery
)
  Marks
    ON  pu.CALOCC_CODE  = Marks.session_code --(+)
    AND pu.PERSON_CODE  = Marks.person_code  --(+)
    AND pu.UIO_ID       = Marks.UIO_ID       --(+)
WHERE
  --pu.CALOCC_CODE = Marks.session_code --(+)
  --and pu.PERSON_CODE = Marks.person_code --(+)
  --and pu.UIO_ID = Marks.UIO_ID --(+)
  --pu.UIO_ID = uio.UIO_ID
  --and uio.OFFERING_ORGANISATION = ou.ORGANISATION_CODE
  --and pu.person_code = p.PERSON_CODE
      pu.UNIT_TYPE              = 'R'
  AND pu.CALOCC_CODE            = :P_Occurrence -- Added Params from master
  AND uio.owning_organisation   = :P_Faculty
  AND uio.OFFERING_ORGANISATION = :P_Division
  AND uio.UIO_ID               IS NOT NULL
  AND uio.FES_ACTIVE            = 'Y'
```

My bigger concern, however, is that you have commented out many `(+)`.  These are obsolete syntax for allowing `OUTER` joins.  This means that the query above still will need to be re-worked, and possibly re-ordered to accommodate any appropriate `LEFT JOIN`, etc.

Comment: That's a much better way of going about it Mat. 

It does need cleaning up, I recently took over these queries from an old system and was tasked to redesign the reports and THEN convert to ANSI. 

I'm aware of the commented out outer joins, they were already done, I believe they were unnecessary since say pu.person_code and Marks.person_code will always match. 

I'll have a go at rewriting them. The original code is hideous anyway.

Thanks Mat!

Answer (score 1):

ou has been defined in the outer most select statement, you can't use it in the inner select statement.

Also, if your SQL looks like this, you should consider braking it to smaller parts by using views for inner select statements. it will be much easier to develop and debug it that way.

Also, what Ben said. stick with one syntax.

Comment: `ou` is defined and referenced in the outer query.  There is a cunningly hidden `)` that you may have missed.  Ignoring the nested queries it is `p, ou, () Marks INNER JOIN uio INNER JOIN pu`.  The problem appears to be a mixture of explicit and implicit join syntax.

Comment: You are correct, I see it now, hiding behind that sysdate :-)...
This makes my suggestion even more necessary - simplified code is simple...